# Por que é utilizado ':' em queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estava vendo um script em php e reparei que toda vez em que se escrevia uma consulta SQL, era utilizado este "operador".

Uma parte do código

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO categorias (nome) VALUES(:nome)";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("nome", $data->nome);
```

Então, qual o motivo dele usar este "operador"?

Comment: A princípio esse operador não existe no MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html). Tem certeza de que não é um símbolo, usado por algum ORM ou Framework de persistência, que indica "bind" de parâmetros (O JPA do Java por exemplo usa atribuição de parâmetros dessa forma)?

Comment: Hum, agora eu entendi, é por causa do "bind"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta sintaxe é utilizada pela `PDO` para anexar parâmetros aos `prepared statements` através da função `bindParam()`.

É bem útil para implementar a segurança na hora de utilizar informações vindas de formulários, ou até mesmo pela dinamicidade de uma query.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 5):

Amigo, você não mostrou todo seu código mas creio que este **=:** não é um "operador".

A interpretação correta seria **=** e **:id**, onde o **:id** está relacionado ao parâmetro de nome **id** que deve ser passado no momento da execução.

Mais informações [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: fiquei meio tonto lendo a explicação :D

Answer (score 4):

Apesar de representarem a mesma coisa, parâmetros e *placeholders* se distinguem na forma como são apresentados num *statement*.

Parâmetros são nomeáveis, permitindo que sejam identificados de forma fácil em meio a todos os termos da pseudo-linguagem SQL. Por se tratar de uma string simples, requer algo que os permitam ser identificados durante a interpretação pelo SGBD. Essa forma de identificação normalmente é o caractere de dois-pontos.

*Placeholders*, no entanto, não são nomeáveis. Eles apenas reservam um lugar para os valores reais. A estes normalmente utiliza-se uma interrogação (?) em meio ao *statement*.

Parâmetros, ou *named placeholders*, tem como vantagem a facilidade de interação com argumentos dinâmicos uma vez que é feita uma associação chave/valor, ou seja, os parâmetros encontrados no *statement* são procurados na lista de parâmetros vinculados e uma substituição simples é feita.

*Placeholders*, porém, são numericamente indexados e são dispostos no *statement* por suas posições e, por isso requerem um pouco mais de atenção, caso contrário você pode acabar acidentalmente vinculando (*binding*) um inteiro à uma coluna no banco que represente um float e, na melhor das hipóteses, receber um resultado incorreto.

---

Antes de saber o porquê dos dois-pontos serem utilizados numa query, você tem de entender o que são *prepared statements* e como eles diferem de uma execução direta.

Vejamos o fluxo de trabalho típico ao se usar um *prepared statement*:

- **Prepare**

É criado um modelo da declaração (statement) pela Aplicação e enviado ao SGBD. Dos valores atribuídos na query, alguns podem ser omitidos. À estes dá-se o nome de parâmetros, *placeholders* ou variáveis vinculadas (*bind variables*).

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (name, price) VALUES (:name, :price)
```

Ou

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (name, price) VALUES (?, ?)
```

O SGBD analisa, compila e executa uma série de [otimizações](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization) no modelo da declaração e armazena o resultado sem executá-lo.

- **Execute**

Mais tarde, a Aplicação fornece (ou vincula - *bind*) valores para os parâmetros e o SGBD executa a declaração possivelmente retornando algum resultado. A Aplicação pode executar a mesma declaração tantas vezes quantas ela precisar, com tantos argumentos diferentes quantos ela puder ou precisar fornecer.

### Por quê usar?

Se compararmos com a execução direta das declarações, *prepared statements* possuem duas principais vantagens:

- O custo, em termos de processamento, para se compilar e otimizar a declaração incorre uma única vez, mesmo que a mesma seja executada múltiplas vezes. No entanto vale salientar que nem todas as técnicas de otimização haja vista que a melhor otimização depende do tipo de argumento recebido assim como a melhor estratégia hoje pode não servir num futuro, próximo ou não, dadas as possíveis mudanças seja na estrutura, sejam nos índices de uma tabela.
- *Prepared statement* são resilientes a Injeção de SQL porque os valores utilizados posteriormente são transmitidos por um protocolo diferente, que não requer que seus dados sejam devidamente escapados.

Há quem diga que *prepared statements* não são tão vantajosos para queries executadas uma única vez dado todos os procedimentos extras e que isso pode ser uma penalidade performática para a Aplicação. Eu discordo pois isso depende de N fatores, desde a escalabilidade do hardware até o quão bem programada a Aplicação foi.