# Formulário Filtros - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estou desenvolvendo uma busca em php para o banco de dados e estou tendo dificuldades, a busca se baseia em filtros, por exemplo:

estado, cidade, quartos, salas ....

***IMAGEM DO FORMULÁRIO ***

[image: IMAGEM DO FORMULÁRIO]

Queria inserir apenas uma query, tipo, eu pensei em passar as condicoes, em todo if, por exemplo, vai passando cada campo

```
if(empty($estado)){
}
else{
 $condicoes = $condicoes + 'estado = '.$estado.' AND ';
}
```

.... assim por diante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, esse tipo de filtro muitas vezes é feito bem desse jeito que você tem em mente. Mas não exatamente como você demonstrou em código.

Primeiro de tudo, óbvio, você deve sanitizar, filtrar e, de repente, até validar os dados recebidos. Confiar no usuário é como ir pra guerra sem capacete.

Depois, você tem duas opções:

1. Montar um array com cada coluna e seu respectivo valor, um a um e, depois de todas as opções consideradas, montar a query concatenando N cláusulas `AND`:

   ```
   $clauses = array();

       if( ! empty( $data['tipoAnunciante'] ) && $data['tipoAnunciante'] != 'none' ) {

           $clauses[] = sprintf( '`tipoAnunciante` = "%s"', $data['tipoAnunciante'] );
       }

       if( ! empty( $data['tipoImovel'] ) && $data['tipoImovel'] != 'none' ) {

           $clauses[] = sprintf( '`tipoImovel` = "%s"', $data['tipoImovel'] );
       }

      // ...
   ```
2. Fazer da forma que o @Luizz sugeriu, num loop. Apesar de que ele usou uma das funções mysql_* que é uma extensão em desuso e não deve ser utilizada.

Ambas as abordagens tem seus prós e contras.

A primeira porque a query não estaria devidamente tratada, preocupação qe não se precisa ter com *prepared statements*, seja da [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO), [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli)...

A segunda porque além de não ser muito legível numa olhada rápida, mesmo que seja usado uma extensão/biblioteca com suporte a *prepared statements* pode vincular o argumento com o tipo errado ou, pior, requere muitas condições dentro do loop.

O mais adequado (ou pelo menos o menos pior) nesse caso, e já considerando *prepared statement* seria algo assim:

```
$columns = array();

if( ! empty( $data['tipoAnunciante'] ) && $data['tipoAnunciante'] != 'none' ) {
    $columns[] = $data['tipoAnunciante'];
}

if( ! empty( $data['tipoImovel'] ) && $data['tipoImovel'] != 'none' ) {
    $columns[] = $data['tipoImovel'];
}

if( ! empty( $data['quartos'] ) && $data['quartos'] != 'none' ) {
    $columns[] = $data['quartos'];
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `tabela`';

if( count( $columns ) > 0 ) {
    $query .= sprintf( ' WHERE `%s` = ?', implode( '` = ? AND `', $columns ) );
}
```

Primeiro nós criamos um array com todas as entradas válidas, isto é, aquelas escolhidas pelo usuário e diferentes de **none** (nenhum, em inglês, opção pessoal minha para o valor *default*).

O pulo do gato está na concatenação final pois além dela só ocorrer se ao menos um filtro tiver sido escolhido, ainda tira proveito de todo verdadeiro poder de [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode)

[implode()](http://www.php.net/implode) não serve unicamente pra transformar um array numa string, veja:

> sprintf( ' **WHERE** *`%s`* = ?', implode( '` = ? AND `', $columns ) );

O termo em negrito adiciona a cláusula WHERE propriamente dita ao final da parte imutável da query.

O termo em itálico (não muito visível) é o **placeholder** de [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/sprintf). Eu poderia usar várias concatenações mas dessa forma é mais legível.

Ele será substituído pela string resultante de [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode). O detalhe, se você observar bem, é que ese *placeholder* está envolto por *backticks* (caractere da crase - `)

Na string da query resultante:

> 'SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `imobiliaria` = ? AND `casa` = ?'

Ele forma o **primeiro** e o **último** *backtick*, à esquerda de `imobiliaria` e à direita de `casa`:

O grande truque está mesmo é no [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode):

> implode( '` = ? AND `', $columns )

Ele vai unir todas as peças, os elementos do array, por:

1. Outro *backtick*;
2. O sinal de igualdade;
3. Uma interrogação (para o *placeholder* do *prepared statement*).
4. A cláusula **AND**
5. Outro *backtick*.

O primeiro *backtick* vai fechar o *backtick* usado no [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/sprintf) e o segundo *backtick* vai abrir o segundo definido nessa função.

Como internamente [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode) trabalha mais ou menos num loop, isso vai se repetir para cada entrada do array. Mas caso tenhamos três ou mais condições (ao invés das duas demonstradas) seu comportamento vai mudar sem você perceber:

- Na primeira "iteração" o primeiro *backtick* vai fechar àquele aberto em [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/sprintf) conforme dito acima e o segundo **vai abrir um novo** para o segundo elemento.
- Na segunda "iteração" o primeiro *backtick* **vai fechar àquele aberto** pela iteração anterior e **abrir um novo** para o terceiro e último elemento.
- Na terceira "iteração" o primeiro *backtick* **vai fechar àquele aberto** pela iteração anterior e o segundo **vai abrir àquele aberto** no [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/sprintf) e a string final está pronta para ser usada.

**Mas e quanto ao tratamento dos valores?**

Pelo menos com a [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) (não sei quanto MySQLi e outras) a menos que você REALMENTE precise da diferença que [PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) e [PDOStatement::bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) têm entre si, você pode simplesmente passar um array para [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) que a própria PDO se encarregará se or argumento for ou precisar ser uma string, um inteiro, um float...

E como as interrogações ~serão adicionadas na exata mesma quantidade de itens no array de valores escolhidos, você não terá problemas com excesso ou falta de interrogações no seu *prepared statement*

Comment: Bom, ficou uma resposta bem grande para um pergunta relativamente simples e o final ficou bastante técnico, mas eu expliquei o melhor que eu pude (considerando as limitações do Markdown daqui) e espero ter podido demonstrar um pouquinho que seja desse "truque" que implode() permite fazer.

Comment: Como você falou, o PDO já não contribui suficiente? Não adianta `tipoAnunciante, tipoImovel...` serem strings limpas, precisam ter os elementos esperados. Não seria o caso de usar um validador junto?

Comment: Não para primeira pergunta e sim para a segunda. Recentemente, enquanto respondia [outro tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26606/por-que-%C3%A9-utilizado-em-queries/26631#26631) aprendi algo que não sabia sobre *prepared statements*: A resiliência dos valores quanto à XSS se dá porque estes trafegam por um protocolo diferente do da query. Não estou dizendo que a PDO não faça nada quando se invoca bindValue()/bindParam() mas, assumindo o pior cenário de que ela não faça mesmo nada, então ela não seria suficiente.

Comment: Mas claro, os dados devem ser externamente sanitizados, filtrados e validados por isso comecei a resposta com esse tipo de informação. Vou apenas editar pra compementar um pouquinho.

Comment: A pergunta dele me pareceu superficial, ainda mais com a resposta escolhida do Luizz, tive ideia que que ele se limitava apenas em prevenir um injection. Fiz um gancho na sua resposta para adentrarmos no PDO :) Eu acompanhei a questão citada, mas você ainda não tinha postado. Muito se discute se o uso do PDO por si só é suficiente, mesmo com PDO você acha que vale sanitizar?

Comment: Eu sou da opinião de que pra algo ser seguro, deve estar fora da Internet, então, sim, cada camada de segurança, cada filtragem, cada forma de prevenção que possa ser possível de se adicionar deve ser adicionada. Talvez quem entenda de C e consiga ler o source do PHP possa nos dar algo mais concreto que diminua esse tipo de paranóia, mas até lá...

Comment: Sempre tive duvida qto o que o uso do PDO pode barrar... Hoje eu tenho tudo pela validação: nome(a-z), idade(0-9), url(regra própria)... Eu tenho minhas limitações com SQL, não passo da superfície. Um input que não satisfaça a regra não vai passar nem perto do DB. Este critério já não resolveria algumas questões de input? Sempre fico com uma pulga atrás da orelha.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15983/discussion-between-bruno-augusto-and-papa-charlie).

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo !

```
$filtroList = array('estado', 'cidade', 'quartos');

$where = array();

foreach ($filtroList as $filtro) {
    if(isset($_GET[$filtro]) === TRUE && is_null($_GET[$filtro]) == FALSE){
        $where[] = $filtro.' = '. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$filtro]);
    }
}

$condicoes = implode(' AND ', $where);
```